# How to check if the user has accepted the "remote-notification" permission on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-permissions

A SDK I'm using in my project prompts the user for the `remote-notification` permission, and I need to know if the user has accepted or rejected this permission so I can show them a custom message.

How would I do that in Objective C? Is it possible to do so?